# Parse JSON serialised by CircularJSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, contentful

I have a JSON object in my node.js code which contains circular references. To send this data to the browser, I used the NPM module [circular-json](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json) to stringify the object and serialise the circular references:

```
var CircularJSON = require("circular-json");
app.get("/api/entries", function(req, res){ 
  contentClient.entries({"content_type": "xxxxxxxxxxx"}, function(err, entries){
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(CircularJSON.stringify(entries));
  });
});
```

This works fine and sends serialised data through `res.send();`
Now, in my frontend Angular code I need to make the circular references usable. One of the serialised fields in the object looks like this on the client side: `"~0~fields~twitter~1"`

I tried the following in the browser:

1. Copied a version of `circular-json.js` to my frontend site
2. Linked to the script in my `index.html` like so: `<script src="/framework/lib/circular-json.js"></script>`
3. Set the `CircularJson` variable like so: `var CircularJSON = window.CircularJSON;`
4. Parse the incoming JSON like so:

   `$http.get("/api/entries").then(function(res){
     console.log(CircularJSON.parse(res.data[0]));
   });`

I get the following error:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

Comment: You probably have to use the same library on the client.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeh I think so but I can't work out how to do that. I followed their guides but it didn't work.

Comment: If you post what you have tried and explain what the issue is, we might be able to help you.

Comment: OK I'll update my question

Comment: @FelixKling I've updated with my frontend code for parsing the JSON

Comment: The error means that you are passing an object to `.parse`, not a string. You have to prevent angular from parsing the response.

Comment: @FelixKling If I don't do something to the object in Angular I have serialised data in the object that I cannot reference. For example `"~0~fields~twitter~1"`

Comment: Maybe my comment wasn't clear: The fact that `CircularJSON.parse(res.data[0])` throws this error means that `res.data[0]` is already an object, not a string containing (circular) JSON. You have to prevent Angluar from parsing the response *automatically*, so that you can parse it *yourself* with `CircularJSON.parse(res.data)`.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah I see what you're saying. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angluar in particular, so I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one time call I think you can use $http as follows

```
function appendTransform(defaults, transform) {

  // We can't guarantee that the default transformation is an array
  defaults = angular.isArray(defaults) ? defaults : [defaults];

  // Append the new transformation to the defaults
  defaults.unshift(transform);
  return defaults;
}

$http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'GET',
  transformResponse: appendTransform($http.defaults.transformResponse,                function(value) {
    return CircularJSON.parse(value);
  })
});
```

Or for every call you can define an interceptors, examples are here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

UPDATE:
Unshift does not return the array. Modified the code, now it should work.

Comment: made a plnkr, you can check it here http://plnkr.co/edit/uXgTzs8e7fJLyWzFPTKX?p=preview